# Ruby on Rails & Prawn PDF - Create Customer List

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, block, prawn

I'm trying to produce a PDF report with Prawn, I can get it to do a report on a show action easily enough by passing the single ID but I want to produce one with every record in it. Like a standard rails scaffold index page. Using rails it would look like this:

```
<% @customer.each do |customer| %>
<%= customer.id %>
<%= customer.name %>
<%end%>
```

Easy!

But I'm not sure how to do this with Prawn..

Something like:

```
def index
 @customer = Customer.all
  respond_to do |format|
  format.html
   Prawn::Document.generate("customer_list.pdf") do |pdf|
   pdf.text "#{@customer.id} "
    pdf.text "#{@customer.name} "  
       end
    end
end
```

Which clearly isn't right.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: I realize you're asking about Prawn but I've had much better experience by generating my reports as HTML/CSS and then converting it to PDF, using the `wkhtmltopdf` app. There is a wrapper gem  called `PDFKit` that makes working with it easy. wkhtmltopdf: http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ and pdfkit: https://github.com/pdfkit/PDFKit   for generating complex reports i find it much easier to generate them in HTML instead of working with PDF/Prawn directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easy to do with **Prawn**, **Gemfile** => gem 'prawn', **bundle**

lets say you have **Customer** model:

**customers_controller.rb**

```
def show
   @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.pdf do
        pdf = CustomerPdf.new(@customer)
        send_data pdf.render, filename: "customer_#{id}.pdf",
                              type: "application/pdf",
                              disposition: "inline"
     end
   end
end
```

then just create **pdfs** folder under the **apps** directory, and create file **customer_pdf.rb**

```
class CustomerPdf< Prawn::Document

  def initialize(customer)
    super()
    @customer = customer
    text "Id\##{@customer.id}"
    text "Name\##{@customer.name}"
  end

end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
  <div class="pdf_link">
    <%= link_to "E-version", customer_path(@customer, :format => "pdf") %>
  </div>
```

**EDIT:**

and don't forget to include pdf to **config/initializers/mime_types.rb**

```
Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf
```

Comment: Won't this display a PDF for just one customer from the show path? I'm trying to get a list of every customer in a table. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this example more shows `customers#show` instead of `customers#index` but the idea is similar. Instead of taking a single `customer` object in the `CustomerPdf` just take your array of customers, iterate over each and call the same `text()` method, then append a newline.

Comment: Awesome! I've been trying to figure this out for a while and I'm unfamiliar with ruby + prawn - this gave me everything I need to get started formatting my PDF. (I think you need a comma after `filename: "customer_#{id}.pdf"` though)

Answer (score 2):

I think the good solution of your problem is custom renderer. The best approach was described by Jose Valim (!Rails core developer) in his [book](http://pragprog.com/book/jvrails/crafting-rails-applications). The beginning of the first chapter is available for free [here](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/jvrails/create.pdf). This chapter is really what you need.

Answer (score 1):

This how I do it:

```
class CustomerPdf< Prawn::Document

 def initialize(customer)
  super(page_size: "A4", page_layout: :portrait)
  @customers = customer
  bullet_list
 end

 def bullet_list
  @customers.each do |customer|
      text "•#{customer.id}- #{customer.name} ", style: :bold
    move_down 5
  end
 end

end
```